# Append then remove element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Trying to append an element on mouseenter then remove the same element on mouseleave.

```
$(#foo).mouseenter(function (){
    $(this).append(#bar);
});
$(#foo).mouseleave(function (){
    $(this).remove(#bar);
});
```

Doesn't work, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Don't you need to quote your selectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quoting string literals appears to be the most obvious thing.  Have you tried:

```
$("#foo").mouseenter(function (){
    $(this).append("#bar");
});
$("#foo").mouseleave(function (){
    $(this).remove("#bar");
});
```

jQuery's element-selector function (i.e. `$()`) expects a string containing a CSS-style selector, like `".someClass"` or `"#someId"` or `"div span.label"`.  Passing those things without quotes around them is a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem, you rock.

Answer (score 2):

```
​$("#foo").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e){
    e.type === "mouseenter"
        ? $("#bar").appendTo(this)
        : $("#bar", this).remove() ;
});​
```

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/AzEnm/1/